# how can I take the value of Text Field and return it in Text but in another screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Todo Add'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              TextField(
                controller: controller,
                onChanged: (value) => title = value,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter your title'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: controller1,
                onChanged: (val) => body = val,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter your body'),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setText();
                },
                child: Text("Submit"),
              ),
              Text(
                'Title : $text',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10,),
              Text(
                'Body : $desc',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Please edit your code it is not readable.

Comment: I put your code in a code block so it's readable, but you'll still need to explain what you're asking (what do you mean by "another screen"?)

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Comment: I want to make an instance of TextField value so I can use this value or print it on any another screen

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text of the TextField with the controllers.

```
String textfield1 = controller.text;
```

And send this variables like arguments to another screen

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
      context,
      route,
      arguments: [controller.text, controller1.text]
    );
```

And get this arguments in the other screen

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```